# Android Bluetooth Bluejacking Possible?

Tags: android, bluetooth, vcf-vcard

Reading from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html,

> The current Android Bluetooth API's require devices to be paired before an RFCOMM connection can be established. (Pairing is automatically performed when you initiate an encrypted
>   connection with the Bluetooth APIs.)

However, to my knowledge, the Bluetooth protocol allows [.vcf (vCard)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) files to be sent without having paired two devices. This is what makes [Bluejacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluejacking) possible on older phones like Sony Ericsson k7** series, Nokia 63** series etc.

In the interests of writing an android bluejacking application I would like to be able to send vCard files from Android without having to first pair with the device. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: One of the key ingredients to bluejacking was to have the phone be discoverable. Most Android phones by default are not discoverable, so this makes it pretty challenging.

Comment: Blue jacking for newer phones is possible, there are a few apps that are out there now that do it, but the names escape me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluejacking is really only sending unsolicited messages to other bluetooth users.  Which is usually confused with [Bluesnarfing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluesnarfing).  Most of the older phones I have worked with in android do not even have Bluetooth discovery turned on which is really the only way someone can do Bluejacking, if they aren't already paired with your phone, they have to see your bluetooth before they can send it.  Usually this discovery mode is only on for 2 minutes , once selected.  Newer phones its a little easier with the easy pairing but I've still had issues making connections.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the phone discoverable for an unlimited period of time, this might be start point for bluejackign to be possible:

> EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION Intent extra. The maximum duration an app can set is 3600 seconds, and a value of 0 means the device is always discoverable.